# Is there any way to import the current desktop background?

Tags: java

I am making snake for a school assignment and have encountered a problem when attempting to make the background clear. It worked before I changed the background color. However, now it will no longer erase anything that has been drawn and then covered up.

For example: when the score changes, the numbers will appear on top of each other, and the snake's previous locations will not erase and he will appear to still be there. I have an idea, which would involve me using the current desktop background.

Class 1:

```
   public class gameWindow extends JFrame {

     public gameWindow() {

add(new SashaOhayonSnakeFST());
setResizable(false);
pack();
setLocationRelativeTo(null);
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     }


     public static void main(String[] args) {

EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() { //Creates queue to run events
  public void run() {          //runs these events on new window 
    JFrame finalWindow = new gameWindow();
    finalWindow.setVisible(true);  
    finalWindow.setBackground(new Color (0,0,0,0));





  }
});
     }
   }
```

(Edited) Class 2:

```
private void draw(Graphics g) {


    if (inGame) {

        g.drawImage(apple, appleCoordinateX, appleCoordinateY, this); //Draws apple


        for (int i = 0; i < dotNum; i++) { //Runs loop to draw each piece of the snake
            if (i == 0) {
                g.drawImage(head, coordinateX[i], coordinateY[i], this); //Draws the head in a different colour to body
            } else {
                g.drawImage(body, coordinateX[i], coordinateY[i], this); //Draws body
            }
        }

      if ((Integer.toString(score*dotNum).length()) >= 3) {
        size = 23;
        fromEdge = 4;
      } else if ((Integer.toString(score*dotNum).length()) >= 4) {
          size = 15;
          fromEdge = 3;
      }
        Font font = new Font("Comic Sans", Font.BOLD, size);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.setFont(font);
        g.drawString(Integer.toString(score*dotNum), fromEdge, 30); //Draws scorekeeper

    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
```

Comment: Can you explain the use of the `desktop background`?

Comment: When using repaint() previously (when the background was black), the ink that used to be on the screen was erased by being covered by the background color. But because the background color is transparent, it is essentially painting over it with nothing, as the background color is now non-existent. By getting the desktop background, i can create my own form of transparency by repainting using the desktop background so that the window conforms into the background.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Graphics2D not clearing transparent image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406750/graphics2d-not-clearing-transparent-image)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set the background color for the content pane of the JFrame, not the JFrame.

```
myJFrame.getContentPane().setBackground( desiredColor );
```

For panels & labels, you must set the item to be Opaque

```
jpanel.setOpaque(true);
```

Comment: Already tried this, it didn't work. The closest i have gotten was using awt.Robot to capture the background of the transparent window and set it as the background, however, this slowed down the game to unplayable speeds.